# Excel formula to pull the second and third word from a filename?

Tags: excel, filenames, formula, formulas

I need a forumula to pull only the second and third word from a filename. The formatting goes like this: "120610 CHELSEA OPTICS.xls". I need a formula so that "CHELSEA OPTICS" will only appear in the cell, without the date in front or the file type in back. I've tried to find this, but haven't found some formula that can remove both the date in front and the file type. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=MID(A1,8,LEN(A1)-12)
```

This supposes that the date is always 6 digits and the file type always 3 characters.

The file name of the current workbook minus the path and extension is:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))+1,(FIND(".",CELL("filename"))-FIND("[",CELL("filename")))-1)
```

As you can see, it is getting quite complicated, but changing 1 to 8 on both sides should get you the part you want:

```
=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))+8,(FIND(".",CELL("filename"))-FIND("[",CELL("filename")))-8)
```

It might be easier to use a User Defined Function, depending on your security settings.

Comment: Thank you! But I inputed it and it only came up with VALUE! after I saved the file. IS there anything I would have needed to add?

Comment: Where is the file name? In a cell? What does it look like?

Comment: No, I'd like to be able to pull the file name from a saved file. The name appears nowhere on the form, but I know it's possible to get the name of a file and display it in a cell.

Comment: Thank you that worked! That is exactly what I was looking for, this is so much help, thank you! I wanted to also know if there is a formula I can use to only get the first word out of the file name? Is there any simple modification I can use?